# Relative positioned div moves when I add static positioned div

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to learn CSS by myself and I don't understand how relative positioning works. My relative positioned div moves to a different place when I add a static positioned div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#static, div#relative {
    height:10px;
    width: 10px;
}

div#static {
    background: red;
    position: static;
}

div#relative {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id=static>
</div>

<div id=relative>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I apply this code the div positioned with relative moves 10px to the left from its normal position but 20px to the bottom. When I only place a div with a relative position it moves 10px left and bottom (like I want it to). Why does it do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both `position: relative` and `position: static` (which is the default, BTW, so any element that has no `position` definition is static) means that the elements are arranged in the flow of all elements according to their settings (height, width, content), in the order in which they appear.

In addition, elements with `position: relative` can have an offset from that position, defined by the top/bottom/left/right parameters. The space reserved for the element however still remains the same as without `position: relative` (but that has no relevance in your situation), the static element takes 10px height, after which the next element begins. Since that next element has `position: relative` and a vertical offset of 10px (defined by the `top: 10px` setting), it's top border appears 20 px below the beginning of the parent element (`body` in this case).

Note: If you add another element after that, it will be overlapped vertically by the relatively positioned element (due to its 10px vertical offset, i.e. `top: 10px`)